# Setting Cache-Control Header in NextJS App Router

Tags: next.js, cache-control

I've been banging my head over this. I'm using NextJS 13's new App Router. I've tried setting the response Cache-Control header via middleware.ts but it doesn't change. I also tried in next.config.js and this also hasn't worked. I have no problems setting custom headers, but NextJS always automatically sets Cache-Control to 'no-store, must-revalidate'. What am I missing? How do I change this header?

Answer (score 4):

NextJS with App Router handles the cache-control header automatically. If you attempt to set it in `next.config.js` [it will be overwritten in production by the build-in caching mechanism](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/headers#cache-control)

In development mode `npm run dev` the cache is `no-store, must-revalidate`.

In production, NextJS 13 uses the SWR strategy (`s-maxage=31536000, stale-while-revalidate`). There are only cache invalidation mechanisms for data fetching and dynamically generated page content.

The initially statically rendered page currently has no mechanism to force a fresh fetch for the end-user at initial load outside of Vercel's hosting ecosystem, which handles this.

If you do not need server-side rendering, I would suggest not using Next, and using Vite. If you do need server-side rendering and don't want to host on Vercel, I would suggest a less black-box framework opinionated for Vercel's ecosystem (like Remix).

Comment: What if I want to use SSR, Next, Vercel etc. but want to have more fine-grained control over cache? For example if I know when content changed and then want to programatically invalidate the cache.

Comment: @sandrooco you will either need to try an older version with the pages router, or you will need to choose a different SSR framework like Remix or SvelteKit which provide more granular control. IMO Next and Vercel are more interested in abstracting away control than building a "runs anywhere" framework.

Comment: Strange, my Next app is sending `private, no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate` in production. Can't figure out what the problem is. It's hosted on vercel (I'm using [next-international](https://github.com/QuiiBz/next-international) so maybe its related?)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it solves your issue, but I might help others, I've spent almost a few days trying to find that piece of docs.

As mentioned, you can't rewrite the `Cache-control` headers, NextJS will always overwrite them (unless you create your middleware on the server level).

But, for static pages, like `/posts` you can add page segment config [revalidate](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#revalidate). It takes a number of seconds and that will be the number in the `Cache-control` header then.

If you're dealing with a dynamic page, as I did, `post/[id]`, NextJS propose to use `fetch` or other cacheable fetch and caches the data on the server, but won't change the headers even if the continent is static.

And there you have the option to use segment config again, [dynamic](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#dynamic), which you can use to force static pages to be dynamic, or a dynamic page to behave as static.

So if you add this code to your dynamic page:

```js
export const dynamic = 'force-static';
export const revalidate = 60;
```

Your headers will look like this: `Cache-control: s-maxage=60, stale-while-revalidate`

That way, you're able to play around with `Cache-control` headers forcing dynamic pages to be static, but I'd suggest always using the `revalidate` option so your pages get updated.

I'm still looking into the revalidation possibilities by converting the page to static, so I'll be glad if someone can add some more hints/caveats to this approach.